# Problem with Excel IF function having too many arguements

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to automate a task for myself to see if I can see if an item is "overdue". However, I also wanted to add in a feature where if the item has been returned, then I won't be warned that that item is overdue. This is what I came up with so far:

`=IF(OR(AND(A2<=TODAY()-14)), AND(D2=returned),"Overdue","Not due")`

I'm currently trialling a 2 week loan period, where if the item is returned not returned within 14 days, I want the B column to show "overdue".

In my excel sheet, I'm currently trying to have cell B2 to show "not due" because while it has been more than 14 days, the item has been "returned" as can be seen from column D.

[My current excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6Hyn.png)

Thank you.

Comment: `=IF(AND(A2<=TODAY()-14,D2<>"returned"),"Overdue","Not due")`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=IF((OR(A2>TODAY(), D2="returned")), "Not Due", "Overdue")
```

- Use the syntax for [Example 2](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/12/03/excel-if-function-iferrror-ifna/) to get a clean OR
- Switch Not Due and Overdue because it is easier to reason about with OR than AND
- Put quotes around "returned". Note you could use `LOWER(D2)` if you want to control for capitalization

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(AND(A2<=(TODAY()-14), D2<>"returned"),"Overdue","Not due")
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.